# How to optimize RUs for Replace of a document in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

I'm a beginner to Azure. I'm using log monitors to view the logs for a Cosmos DB resource. I could see one log with Replace operation which is consuming a lot of average RUs.

Generally operation names should be CREATE/DELETE/UPDATE/READ . But why REPLACE operation has come in place over here - I could not understand it. And why the REPLACE operation is consuming lot of RUs?

What can I try next?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but... Cosmos DB doesn't have an "update" API. Rather, you must replace an existing document (and you would typically read the existing document first, and modify it, before replacing it).

Comment: As far as optimizing RUs, that's a really broad topic, and doesn't really fit well as a question here (since you'll get opinion-based solutions that aren't directly related to your particular case).. I would suggest editing your question to be specific (including exact operations you're doing, sample data, etc). Note that there is quite a bit of documentation published around RU planning & optimization (as well as docs for the various APIs, such as Replace mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks David .. Can u please provide some docs for cosmos Mongo API RU optimisation ?

Comment: Cosmos DB does have a PATCH API now. But I think this is not necessarily any cheaper RU-wise. Just makes some scenarios easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates in Cosmos are full replacement operations rather than in-place updates, as such these consume more RU/s than inserts. Also, the larger the document, the more throughput required for the update.

Strategies to optimize throughput consumption on update operations typically center around splitting documents into two with properties that don't change going into one document that is typically larger and another document with those properties that change frequently going into an other that is smaller. This will allow for the updates to be made on a smaller document which reduces RU/s consumed to do the operation.

All that said, 12 RU/s is not an inordinate amount of RU/s for a replace operation. I don't think you will get much, if any throughput reduction doing this. But you can certainly try.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark Brown for your suggestion. Can you please suggest some references for Cost Analysis of cosmos db ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by cost analysis but this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-throughput) has information on how to optimize throughput cost.